# How to get the current system cursor and save it to file xxx.cur?

Tags: c#, wpf, cursor

I know how set the system cursor from xxx.cur file, but I want to know how to save the current system cursor to a file.

In WPF, set system cursor can use the following code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string lpFileName);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern bool SetSystemCursor(IntPtr hcur, uint id);
internal const uint OCR_NORMAL = 32512;
IntPtr hAni = Win32Api.LoadCursorFromFile("file.cur");
bool b = SetSystemCursor(hAni, Win32Api.OCR_NORMAL);
```

But I don't know how to save the current system cursor to the disk.

Can anyone tell me, thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering why you'd need to? The cursor is a user preference, not something a user would changed without permission.

Comment: I will add options in my application for user to switch whatever cursor they like. So I need to know how to switch back to system default cursor by using c# in WPF.

Comment: What I'm getting at is: Do you need to set it system wide or just for the current app? Much easier if just for the current app.

Comment: I have already set it system wide. Next I want to get the system cursor and save it to disk.

Comment: It is already on disk.  From VS, use File + Open + File and select c:\windows\system32\user32.dll.  Open the Cursor node and double click the numbered items.  Right-click + Save to save to a file.  I seriously doubt this is legal btw.  And just not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is potentially a bit ugly and the code I'm posting is not factored very nicely (it's rough to describe the solution), but you can pull the current cursors from the registry and then save them back out again.

```
public class UserCursors
{
    [Serializable]
    internal enum ImageType
    {
        Bitmap = 0,
        Icon = 1,
        Cursor = 2,
        EnhMetafile = 3,
    }

    [Serializable, Flags]
    internal enum LoadImageFlags
    {
        DefaultColor = 0x0,
        Monochrome = 0x1,
        Color = 0x2,
        CopyReturnOriginal = 0x4,
        CopyDeleteOriginal = 0x8,
        LoadFromFile = 0x10,
        LoadTransparent = 0x20,
        DefaultSize = 0x40,
        VgaColor = 0x80,
        LoadMap3DColors = 0x1000,
        CreateDibSection = 0x2000,
        CopyFromResource = 0x4000,
        Shared = 0x8000,
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadImage(IntPtr hinst, String lpszName, ImageType uType, Int32 cxDesired, Int32 cyDesired, LoadImageFlags fuLoad);

    public IntPtr hInst = IntPtr.Zero;
    public String lpszName;
    public Int32 width = 0;
    public Int32 height = 0;
    public string regKeyName = String.Empty;
    public bool Changed = false;

    public UserCursors()
    {

    }

    public UserCursors(string cursorLocation, string keyName)
    {
        hInst = LoadImage(IntPtr.Zero, cursorLocation, ImageType.Cursor, width, height, LoadImageFlags.LoadFromFile);
        lpszName = cursorLocation;
        regKeyName = keyName;
    }
}
```

Then create a list for example

```
public List<UserCursors> systemCursors;
```

Load up the list

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetSystemCursor(IntPtr hcur, uint id);
const uint OCR_NORMAL = 32512;
const uint OCR_HAND = 32649;
const uint OCR_IBEAM = 32513;

        IntPtr hArrow = LoadImage(IntPtr.Zero, "<my custom cursor file>", ImageType.Cursor, width, height, LoadImageFlags.LoadFromFile);
        IntPtr hHand = LoadImage(IntPtr.Zero, "<my custom cursor file>", ImageType.Cursor, width, height, LoadImageFlags.LoadFromFile);
        IntPtr hBeam = LoadImage(IntPtr.Zero, "<my custom cursor file>", ImageType.Cursor, width, height, LoadImageFlags.LoadFromFile);

        RegistryKey myCursors = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(defaultCursors);
        string[] keyCursors = myCursors.GetValueNames();
        bool beamFound = false;
        int lastError = 0;

        foreach (string cursorKey in keyCursors)
        {
            RegistryValueKind rvk = myCursors.GetValueKind(cursorKey);
            switch (rvk)
            {
                case RegistryValueKind.ExpandString:
                    string cursorValue = myCursors.GetValue(cursorKey) as string;
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cursorValue))
                    {
                        UserCursors currentSystemCursor = new UserCursors(cursorValue, cursorKey);
                        switch (cursorKey)
                        {
                            case "Arrow":
                                currentSystemCursor.Changed = SetSystemCursor(hArrow, OCR_NORMAL);
                                break;
                            case "Hand":
                                currentSystemCursor.Changed = SetSystemCursor(hHand, OCR_HAND);
                                if (!currentSystemCursor.Changed)
                                {
                                    lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                                    Win32Exception ex = new Win32Exception(lastError);
                                }
                                break;
                            case "IBeam":
                                beamFound = true;
                                currentSystemCursor.Changed = SetSystemCursor(hBeam, OCR_IBEAM);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        systemCursors.Add(currentSystemCursor);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        // if a user hasn't customised the IBeam then it doesn't appear in the registry so we still change it
        // and then clear the value to remove it.
        if (!beamFound)
        {
            UserCursors currentSystemCursor = new UserCursors("C:\\Windows\\Cursors\\beam_i.cur", "IBeam");
            currentSystemCursor.Changed = SetSystemCursor(hBeam, OCR_IBEAM);
            systemCursors.Add(currentSystemCursor);
        }
```

and then in the destructor or finalize or similar

```
    ~MainWindow()
    {
        int lastError = 0;
        bool changed = false;

        foreach (UserCursors savedCursor in systemCursors)
        {
            if (savedCursor.Changed)
            {
                switch (savedCursor.regKeyName)
                {
                    case "Arrow":
                        changed = SetSystemCursor(savedCursor.hInst, OCR_NORMAL);
                        if (!changed)
                        {
                            lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                            Win32Exception ex = new Win32Exception(lastError);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "Hand":
                        changed = SetSystemCursor(savedCursor.hInst, OCR_HAND);
                        if (!changed)
                        {
                            lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                            Win32Exception ex = new Win32Exception(lastError);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "IBeam":
                        changed = SetSystemCursor(savedCursor.hInst, OCR_IBEAM);
                        if (!changed)
                        {
                            lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                            Win32Exception ex = new Win32Exception(lastError);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```